# What does transversal mean?

Tags: matrices, terminology

I am reading a paper for my seminar talk in numerical mathematics. I am getting to this line.

> Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times q}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times (n-q)}$ and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{(n-p)\times q}$.
>
> $B$ spans a subspace transversal to the range of $A$ and $C$ spans a subspace transversal to the range of $A^T$.

Since I am not a native english speaker I want to be sure I understood the context correctly.
My guess would be that B is the complement of the subspace generated by the columns of A. The same for C be the complement of $A^T$. Or does it refer to be the orthogonal complement?

I am very happy for every help.
Thanks,
Hypertrooper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E$ be a vector space and let $F$ and $G$ be subvector spaces, then $F$ and $G$ are transversal if and only if:
$$E=F+G.$$
Please note that it is not required that the sum is direct, namely $F\cap G$ can have a non-negative dimension.

Actually, $F$ and $G$ are transversal if and only if $\textrm{codim}(F)+\textrm{codim}(G)=\textrm{codim}(F\cap G)$.